# use django's reverse function in req.path

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-1.9

I was stumbling on invitation feature to understand how it works. I found the blog post on http://www.pythondiary.com/tutorials/create-invite-only-website.html. There the author says (It checks the path as this will cause an infinite loop if not checked). How to use reverse function to check the path?

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    INVITE_CHOICES = (
    ('G', 'General'),
    ('I', 'Invitational'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    cookie = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('user_mgmt:confirm_invite', kwargs={'token': self.token})

class InvitedMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, req):
        if req.path == '/i.auth': # what path is this?
            return None
        if not req.user.is_authenticated():
            if 'token' in req.COOKIES:
                return redirect('user_mgmt.views.login_user')
        return None

    def process_response(self, req, resp):
        if req.user.is_authenticated():
            if req.user.is_staff:
                return resp
            if 'token' in req.COOKIES:
                token = req.COOKIES['token']
            else:
                invite = Invite.objects.get(user=req.user)
                token = invite.token
            resp.set_cookie('token', token, MAX_AGE=1209600)
        return resp
```

Comment: You must share your `urls.py` to help you with

Comment: I have not understand the req.path so i have not created the urls yet. Is it the url/path for login?

Comment: In order to understand the `reverse` function (that's what you are asking, right?) you must implement the `urls.py`

Comment: The problem is i did not understand the req.path part. What is he checking there? Which path he is refering? Can you show me an example what url you will create based on the condition he has used? Will it be different when using django-allauth?

Comment: In models.py i have used the reverse function and there i know why i have used reverse function and also what path to give but unaware on req.path part. What do you think it will be? Can you please make me the concept clear?

Answer (score 0):

OK. But first notice that this example uses the old `Middleware` declaration and syntax. When you are comfortable, switch to the new [`Middleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/) syntax. In addition it was written 5 years ago (!), where a lot has changed in Django since then!

Recalling from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#middleware-order-and-layering):

> You can think of it (*the middleware*) like an onion: each middleware class is a “layer”
>   that wraps the view, which is in the core of the onion. If the request
>   passes through all the layers of the onion [...], all the way to
>   the view at the core, the response will then pass through every layer
>   (in reverse order) on the way back out.

So, what the author does here is this:

Depending on the order of appearance of the `InvitedMiddleware` inside [`MIDDLEWARE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE) setting, the `InvitedMiddleware` will be called before each `view` call. It checks if the `request.path` (i.e the url that is about to call a `view`, that is about to render a template - or not) is `'/i.auth'` (i.e `127.0.0.1:8000/i.auth/`. If it is, then he returns `None` (the view is never called). Now, he does that, its unknown. He says that *we'll get to what this path does later* but he never does (!). Maybe there is a second series of this tutorial, who knows?

Anyway, if the requested path is not `'/i.auth'` then another check is performed. If the user is not authenticated. But I think its pretty straightforward from here on. Remember, all these happen before the view is called.

If, now you used the [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) method it should look like this:

```
if req.path == reverse('url_name', ...):
```

where `...` are any potential positional `args` or/and `kwargs`.

But the author of that post, does not define somewhere this URL. Nor he is explain the structure of it. I think it is safe to pass that and continue with the rest.

Comment: I am too interested on this. How would you structure your url? Do we have to use EXEMPT_URL?

Comment: The question is *what do you want this url for?*. Why you must check it? The author says about an infinite loop, but he never shows the `urls.py`.

Comment: What can be i.auth ?

Comment: I understand the middleware concept but i am still confused on urls part. What url should i give then?